# Superposition principle in electrostatics

Tags: electrostatics, superposition, linear-systems

Poisson's equation in electrostatic does not satisfy the linear superposition principle. Can I say that since Laplacian operator is a non-linear operator so it does not follow the linear superposition principle or something more else?

Comment: Laplacian operator is a non-linear operator??

Comment: Surely $\nabla^2(f+g)=\nabla^2 f+\nabla^2 g$...

Comment: sorry I was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poisson's equation is

$$
\nabla^2V=\rho
$$

It is true that if you put in $V_1$ and $V_2$ as solutions to Poisson's equations, then $V_1+V_2$ would *not* satisfy Poisson's equation, because

$$
\nabla^2(V_1+V_2)=\nabla^2 V_1+\nabla^2 V_2=\rho+\rho=2\rho\neq\rho
$$

Note that this is *not* because $\nabla^2$ is not a linear operator. $\nabla^2$ is just a bunch of derivatives, so emphatically is a linear operator. $\nabla^2(V_1+V_2)=\nabla^2 V_1+\nabla^2 V_2$, so it's linear. The problem is that the *other* side of the equation is not linear in $V$. The other side of the equation gives you back $\rho$ whether you put in $V_1$, $V_2$, or $V_1+V_2$ into the equation.

If you want to think of this in terms of operators, the left side of the equation has the $\nabla^2$ operator. When you specify a $V$, it gives you back $\nabla^2V$. This is a linear operator. The right side of the equation has the $\rho$ "operator". When you specify a $V$, it gives you back $\rho$. No matter what $V$ you plug in, it always gives you back the same $\rho$. This is not a linear operator. Thus, since your equation doesn't look like $(\text{linear operator})V=(\text{other linear operator})V$, it is not a linear equation.

Comment: Should the second equation equal $\rho_1 +\rho_1 $ rather than $2\rho$?

Comment: @user45664 we're assuming $V_1$ and $V_2$ are solutions to the SAME equation. So they have identical $\rho$.

Comment: But then your second equation shows that $\nabla^2$ is linear?  Am I confused with the wording?

Comment: @user45664 $\nabla^2$ IS linear, that's the point. The point is that Poisson's equation *as a whole* is not linear, because if $V_1$ and $V_2$ are solutions, then $V_1+V_2$ is NOT a solution. That's precisely because you have $2\rho$ on the RHS when you wanted just $\rho$.

Comment: @user45664 Perhaps the confusion is coming from what exactly I'm defining to be Poisson's equation. I'm saying someone hands you a *fixed* $\rho$, the charge density of your system, and you want to solve $\nabla^2 V=\rho$. That's Poisson's equation. Then $V_1+V_2$ is a solution to a DIFFERENT equation, one where the charge density in your system was doubled. It DOESN'T satisfy your equation, which was given for a certain, fixed $\rho$.

Comment: Re. "...if V1 and V2 are solutions, then V1+V2 is NOT a solution."

Is it not true that $\nabla^2(V1+V2)=\nabla^2(V1)+\nabla^2(V2)$?  Then that statement would be wrong--Ie.  Poisson's equation as a whole is linear.

Comment: @user45664 What you've said is true. $\nabla^2 (V_1+V_2)=\nabla^2 V_1+\nabla^2 V_2$. But as I showed above, if $V_1$ and $V_2$ both satisfy $\nabla^2 V_i=\rho$, then $(V_1+V_2)$ does NOT satisfy $\nabla^2(V_1+V_2)=\rho$. Thus, $V_1+V_2$ is NOT a solution to the equation $\nabla^2 V=\rho$.

Comment: @user45664 This occurs *precisely because* $\nabla^2(V_1+V_2)=\nabla^2V_1+\nabla^2V_2$. Without this fact, I couldn't have proven by second equation. I'm *not* claiming that $\nabla^2$ is nonlinear. I'm saying that *even though* $\nabla^2$ *is* linear, the Poisson equation is not linear.

Comment: @user45664 Again: All I mean is that if $\nabla^2 V_1=\rho$ and $\nabla^2 V_2=\rho$, then $\nabla^2(V_1+V_2)\neq \rho$. Thus, the equation is not a linear equation, because the sum of two solutions is not a solution. If you disagree with this, it might be helpful to say specifically WHERE you disagree: Do you think $\nabla^2(V_1+V_2)= \rho$? Do you agree $\nabla^2(V_1+V_2)\neq \rho$ but still think the equation is linear?

Comment: "Do you agree ∇2(V1+V2)≠ρ but still think the equation is linear?"--yes, but we better end the discussion because its getting too long.